# How to get onload event of a material stepper in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I have a material-vertical-stepper in my application, which is shown inside a bootstrap modal. I have used (selectionChange) directive inside mat-vertical-stepper to track the onchange event. But it is not triggered initially. My stepper data is dynamic and steps are listed based on db values. I need to execute a function when the mat stepper is loaded and this need to be executed once. Any help please.

```
<mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="true" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100" fxLayoutAlign="stretch" #stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" (selectionChange)="loadPattern($event)">
     <mat-step *ngFor="let template of TemplateArray; let i = index" fxFlex="100"  fxLayout="column">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Pattern {{i + 1}}  </ng-template>
     </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: I think what you want is to check if your data is loaded and then conditionnaly apply your stepper. I am not sure if I completely understand what you want but it is unrelated to the stepper itself. What do you expect the function to do when the mat stepper is displayed ?

Comment: Could you post the complete code?

Comment: Thanks for your response edkeveked. Data is loaded and is working. But how can i track if the stepper is loaded. Any event like (selectionChange)  available for on load

Comment: @LppEdd I have editted my question.  Code is updated.

Comment: @YaduChandran but I don't understand, what do you want to be notified about? The event you're looking for what data does it have to pass to you?

Comment: @LppEdd First step is always active in material stepper. I have included an ng-template inside each step dynamically. When user changes any step manually a function is triggered and an operation takes place. This works fine when the users changes the steps manually. But initially it wont work. I have made this mat-vertical-stepper inside a modal. ngAfterViewInit still showing undefined.

Comment: @YaduChandran what is still `undefined`?

Comment: @LppEdd inside ngAfterViewInit MatStepper is undefined. My stepper is inside a modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198346/discussion-between-yadu-chandran-and-lppedd).

Comment: did you find the answer?